# Comunicación entre componentes con hooks en reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-navigation, react-redux, programación-reactiva

Estoy consumiendo una api y el json que me devuelve quiero enviárselo a otro componente para ahí mostrarlo, pero no se como hacerlo, estoy usando hooks, he visto que hay ejemplos pero con clases :C.
Gracias de antemano.

```js
import React, { useState,useEffect } from 'react';
import User from '../user/index.js';

const UserList = () => {
   const  [planets,setPlanets ]= useState([]);
 
    async function fetchData(){
        const res = await fetch("https://swapi.co/api/planets/");
        res.json()
        .then(res => setPlanets(res.results))
        .catch(err => console.log(err));
    }
    useEffect(()=>{
        fetchData();
    });

    const variable = "Hola variable";
    return(
        <div>
            <User />
        </div>
    )
}

export default UserList;
```

```js
import React from 'react';

const User = () =>{
    return(
        <div></div>
    )
}

export default User;
```

Comment: Buenas, puedes indicar que datos quieres pasar. Entiendo que quieres pasar datos a User, pero sería mejor que lo aclares

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para enviar data a componentes tienes que usar los `props`

```js
import React, { useState,useEffect } from 'react';
import User from '../user/index.js';

const UserList = () => {
   const  [planets,setPlanets ]= useState([]);
 
async function fetchData(){
    const res = await fetch("https://swapi.co/api/planets/");
    res.json()
    .then(res => setPlanets(res.results))
    .catch(err => console.log(err));
}
useEffect(()=>{
    fetchData();
});

const variable = "Hola variable";
return(
    <div>
        <User variable={variable} planets={planets} />
    </div>
)
}

export default UserList;
```

Luego desde tu componente puedes leer estos props:

```js
import React from 'react';

const User = (props) =>{
return(
  <div>
    <div>Planets: {props.planets}</div>
    <div>Variable: {props.variable}</div>
  </div>
)
}

export default User;
```

Comment: Ya lo habia resuelto pero muchas gracias igual