# ¿Cómo leer las propiedades de un objeto dentro de un array en JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, array, reactjs, react-hooks, javascript-objeto

Estoy tratando de leer las propiedades de un objeto de javascript guardado dentro de un array en un componente de react hooks. este objeto tiene las siguientes propiedades:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En react, guardo este array de esta función:

```
const obtenerPermisosColumnas = async () => {
  let config = { headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },  withCredentials: true };
  let resultado = await axios.get('api/buscarRolPorId/' + id_rol, config)
  .then(res => {
    let datos_roles = res.data;
    permisos.push(datos_roles);
    
    if(permisos[0].editar_numero_amparo === true || permisos[0].consultar_juicios === true) {
      columnas.push({
        title: 'No. de Amparo',
        field: 'numero_amparo'
      });
    }
              
    if(permisos[0].editar_juzgado === true || permisos[0].consultar_juicios === true) {
      columnas.push({
        title: 'Juzgado de Distrito',
        field: 'juzgado'
      })
    }     
    
    return datos_roles;
                  
  });
          
  if(permisos.length > 0 && columnas.length > 0){
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}
```

intento acceder al objeto de esta forma, imprimiéndolo en consola:

```
console.log("permisos afuera de función: ", permisos);
```

Pero cuando quiero acceder a una propiedad en especifico, siempre recibo un `undefined`. He intentado acceder a ella en las siguientes formas:

```
console.log("permisos: ", permisos['0']['asignar_permisos']);
console.log("permisos: ", permisos['0'].asignar_permisos);
console.log("permisos: ", permisos[0].asignar_permisos);
console.log("permisos: ", permisos.asignar_permisos);
```

Pero todas me mandan `undefined`.

**¿Cómo puedo acceder a estas propiedades?**

Gracias de antemano amigos.

Comment: Hasta donde se ve en tu código no esta declarado `permisos` , ya que usas `await` podrías usar `resultado.data` y eso probablemente te retorne igualmente el arreglo y evitas usar `permisos.push` ayudando un poco a simplificar tu código.

Answer (score 0):

Para evitar un poco esos errores y aprovechar el `await` que parece que no se aprovecha en nada, lo aremos de la siguiente forma.

```
const obtenerPermisosColumnas = async () => {
    let config = { headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }, withCredentials: true };
    let resultado = await axios.get('api/buscarRolPorId/' + id_rol, config);
    permisos.push(resultado.data); // de esta forma es seguro que tiene ya la data deseada


    if (permisos[0].editar_numero_amparo === true || permisos[0].consultar_juicios === true) {
        columnas.push({
            title: 'No. de Amparo',
            field: 'numero_amparo'
        });
    }

    if (permisos[0].editar_juzgado === true || permisos[0].consultar_juicios === true) {
        columnas.push({
            title: 'Juzgado de Distrito',
            field: 'juzgado'
        })
    }
    

    if (permisos.length > 0 && columnas.length > 0) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Por ejemplo, para hacer eso dentro de un Array State en react, ¿Se hace de la misma forma?

Comment: @SthefanyRangel si es casi de la misma forma, lo único que cambia es que tienes que realizar el cambio de estado al ingresar un elemento nuevo en tu state

Comment: @SthefanyRangel una forma sencilla de agregar elementos a tu state es de esta forma `setMyArrayState(e=>[...e,'otro elmento']);`

Comment: al parrecer si lo paso de un componente padre a un hijo no puedo acceder todavía a esas propiedades, intentando los mismos `console.log` No ayuda mucho. ¿Cómo se podrían acceder si lo tomamos como un props de un componente funcional de react?

Comment: @SthefanyRangel Para ayudarte mejor con ese problema, puedes publicar tu pregunta con la información necesaria para recibir una respuesta, ya que de esta forma se me hace complicado saber cual es el error que recibes o problema que presentas.

Comment: @SthefanyRangel Puedes revisar la siguiente respuesta sobre la [comunicación entre componentes](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/326600/76401)